# Kotlin - Set is having duplicate element but no error is coming

Tags: kotlin, duplicates, set

In below Set is having duplicate elements but no error is coming after compilation,

```
val set = mutableSetOf("a", "a", "a")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set data structure does not throw errors on duplicates. It just ignores them. If you print contents of your set you will see it contains only a single item:

```
val set = mutableSetOf("a", "a", "a")
println(set)
// [a]
```

Comment: You can see that from the docs for [`MutableSet.add()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/add.html), which returns `false` (without throwing an exception) if the item is already present.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the exception for some reason, you can write a helper function:

```
fun <T> mutableSetOfUniqueElements(varargs elements: T): MutableSet<T> {
    val result = mutableSetOf<T>()
    for (e in elements) {
        if (!result.add(e)) {
            throw InvalidArgumentException("Duplicate element")
        }
    }
    return result
}
```